# Eclipse RCP plugin dependencies

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to generate an RCP product from a set of Eclipse plugin. When I am trying to run the Eclipse plugin from my Eclipse.rcp.product plugin, Eclipse is asking me to add all the dependent plugins. I have done that.

However, on adding a new plugin, it starts asking for dependencies (e.g., third party libraries from Eclipse's Orbit repo) of that plugin too. All the dependencies of individual plugins are referenced in those plugins.

Why do I have to add all the references again in the RCP plugin. What is the way around or right way?

Answer (score 2):

The xxx.product file must list every plugin that your RCP is going to use as this list determines what is included in the resulting product.

This is a separate list from the individual plugin dependencies.

The Dependencies tab of the .product file editor has an 'Add Required' button which should add everything that is needed (assuming you have already added all your plugins).

You can also use 'features' rather than 'plugins' for the product file which reduces the number of things that need to be included in the dependencies.

Comment: My xxx.product plugin is based on features. I am using features from another repository developed by another group of developers. However, I don't see my plugins there when I click on add. Do I need to convert my plugin first into a feature? I could add my plugins in xxx.rcp plugin but there it is asking me to add all dependencies one by one for each individual plugin which are already added in those plugins.

Comment: Yes, it would be best to convert put your plugins in a feature

Comment: I have created a feature that contains all my plugins. In the dependency tab of feature I clicked compute and got all dependencies automatically added. I added this feature into my xxx.rcp.product plugin but I am still getting same errors: add the kkk dependency (e.g., a referenced library in orbit). When I add that kkk dependency in xxx.rcp, the error goes away but then it starts asking for all other dependencies one by one.

Comment: Exactly what is asking for these dependencies?

Comment: My plugin hierarchy is like this:
xxx.totalads.core
xxx.totalads.ui
and two more test plugins
then there is a  xxx.totalads (feature plugin)
I added this xxx.totalads feature to xxx.rcp.product plugin
My errors are as follows:
`
ENTRY org.eclipse.tracecompass.totalads.core 4 0 2014-12-23 11:06:50.845
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.tracecompass.totalads.core [251]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb; bundle-version="2.10.1"
`